# Extracting a branch/node of a JSON as a new JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I use Nuki Smartlock and the Nuki Bridge gives me back these JSON for two different API-Calls and I want to use the same logic for working with the answers:

And if I call for the current states, I get this JSON:

```
[{
  "deviceType": 0,
  "nukiId": 1234,
  "name": "NukiDoor",
  "firmwareVersion": "2.9.10",
  "lastKnownState": {
    "mode": 2,
    "state": 3,
    "stateName": "unlocked",
    "batteryCritical": false,
    "batteryCharging": false,
    "batteryChargeState": 72,
    "doorsensorState": 2,
    "doorsensorStateName": "door closed",
    "timestamp": "2021-01-04T13:02:52+00:00"
  }
}]
```

and if I call a Action (e.g. opening the door), I get this JSON as a bonus:

```
{
  "deviceType": 0,
  "nukiId": 1234,
  "mode": 2,
  "state": 3,
  "stateName": "unlocked",
  "batteryCritical": "OFF",
  "batteryCharging": "OFF",
  "batteryChargeState": 72,
  "doorsensorState": 2,
  "doorsensorStateName": "door closed"
}
```

So, as you can see, the node .lastKnowState from the Status-Request equals the pure JSON from the Action-JSON.

So, how can I "extract" the node lastKnownState from the first JSON to have it the same way as the second one using JavasScript?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user is asking how to access an array item at index, which is incredibly trivial and is easily answered by google. Therefore this question provides little(if any) value to the community.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are receiving is a JSON array with one JSON object that contains another JSON object, namely `lastKnownState`. Since there is just one object in the array, you need to extract the `0th` index, that will give you the JSON object that wraps your `lastKnownState`, and then you need to use dot operator to extract the JSON that represents `lastKnownState`

I am posting the answer below, but it would be helpful to read up on how to do various operations on JSON objects and arrays. Here is a neat guide:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics

Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

```js
const data = [{
  "deviceType": 0,
  "nukiId": 1234,
  "name": "NukiDoor",
  "firmwareVersion": "2.9.10",
  "lastKnownState": {
    "mode": 2,
    "state": 3,
    "stateName": "unlocked",
    "batteryCritical": false,
    "batteryCharging": false,
    "batteryChargeState": 72,
    "doorsensorState": 2,
    "doorsensorStateName": "door closed",
    "timestamp": "2021-01-04T13:02:52+00:00"
  }
}];

const lastKnownState = data[0].lastKnownState;

console.log(lastKnownState, null, 2)
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), and no "JSON Array", and see the CV comment on the question.

Comment: You are being too pedantic, and you know what I mean here. If you go to https://www.json.org/json-en.html they mention Object as the notations that contain within `{}` and Arrays as the notations that contain within `[]`. Just because the question is too basic does not mean the answer has to be downvoted. It adds values by redirecting to right learning resources.

Comment: It's either an object, an array or JSON. But not a "JSON Object" or a "JSON Array" because those things just don't exist.

Comment: Thanks, i had the [0] missing, of course! 
Thank you!